# How can we set the resolution of a BigDecimal so it can only ever take values that land in specified increments?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Is it possible to set the resolution of the BigDecimal e.g. to 10<sup>–9</sup>, so values must be multiples of this value and nothing less.

Or does this have to be done when performing arithmetic operations via rounding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for

```
    BigDecimal val1 = new BigDecimal("1.00876876989",MathContext.DECIMAL128);

    // setting the scale to 10 sets the limits resolution, but the precision provided by the MathContext must be big enough to support this minimum resolution.
    // The rounding type doesn't matter but must be provided.

    val1 = val1.setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```